# How can I compare and represent the categorical data of my two columns with 0 if the rows are the same and 1 if not, using R

Tags: r, if-statement, compare, row, categorical-data

How can I compare the categorical data of my two columns and visualize it with a 0 if the row is the same for the two columns and if different 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the categorical columns of your dataframe are named `x` and `y` and have the same `levels` you can assign a new column to your dataframe with the result of comparing the two columns using the `ifelse` function.

```
df$match <- ifelse(df$x == df$y, 0, 1)
```

Comment: How about when I want to compare the categorical column x with itself, y and z. If x is equal with its own represent it with 0, if it equal with y 1 and if equal with z 2.